# Sorting elements by edited attribute

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to merge two XML files "a.xml" and "b.xml" into a HTML table using XSLT 1.0. Both files contain elements called "event" that each have a "time" attribute with a dateTime value attached to them. I want the HTML table to be sorted chronologically. Whereas the time attributes of file "a.xml" are formated correctly (CCYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.msmsms), the time attributes of "b.xml" are not (CCYY-DDDTHH:MM:SS.msmsmsZ) and thus I am using some concats and substring functions to construct the correct format for the "time" attributes of the "b.xml" elements. My question is now: How can I use the original "time" attributes of "a.xml" and the corrected attributes of "b.xml" for sorting the rows of the HTML table?

I already tried using parameters for storing the correctly formated "time" attributes. I also tried using node-sets to tackle the issue in two steps (i.e. converting "b.xml" attributes first, saving result and then creating the HTML from the intermediate file), but neither of these two ways worked for me. Lastly I tried sorting the HTML table on load of the page with a JavaScript, but the table is too big for doing it this way on each page load.

I am happy about every hint on a functionality of XSLT that could help me. I have to stick with XSLT1.0, though and can't use XSLT2.0 for this project.

**a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <event time="2019-02-03T06:00:00.000"></event>
    <event time="2019-02-01T06:00:00.000"></event>
</data>
```

**b.xml before formating**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <event time="2019-035T06:00:00.000"></event>
    <event time="2019-033T06:00:00.000"></event>
</data>
```

**b.xml after formating**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <event time="2019-02-04T06:00:00.000"></event>
    <event time="2019-02-02T06:00:00.000"></event>
</data>
```

**current transform.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Adata/event|document('b.xml')/Bdata/event">
            <xsl:sort select="@time"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Bdata/event">
<!--Here I have some long operation to change the date format and save it as parameter "correctFormat"-->
    <xsl:attribute name="time">
        <xsl:value-of select="$correctFormat"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//event">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@time"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**expected output out.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
            <tr><td>2019-02-01T06:00:00.000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2019-02-02T06:00:00.000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2019-02-03T06:00:00.000</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2019-02-04T06:00:00.000</td></tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

**Date conversion code**

As requested I share as well my code for the conversion. I am using the exslt dates and time namespace by adding  inside the header

```
<xsl:template match="data/event">
<xsl:param name="daysToAdd" select="concat('P',substring(@time,6,3),'D')"/>
<xsl:param name="startOfYear" select="concat(substring(@time,1,4),'-01-00')"/>
<xsl:param name="formatedDate">
    <xsl:call-template name="date:add">
               <xsl:with-param name="date-time" select="$startOfYear" />
               <xsl:with-param name="duration" select="$daysToAdd" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(@time,9,13)"/>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="time">
        <xsl:value-of select="$formatedDate"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you have code to correct the date format in the secondary input, why can't you run it through a separate stylesheet first that transforms the dates to the correct format? Or, if you have "also tried using node-sets to tackle the issue in two steps (i.e. converting "b.xml" attributes first, saving result and then creating the HTML from the intermediate file)", the show us the details of the code, the result you expected and the result or errors you got.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MartinHonnen! To be honest I haven't tried running through a separate file first as my goal was to have a single working xsl file. I tried separating the two functions and the output is sorted as expected! So, maybe I should rephrase my question to: How can I make the two steps "changing date format" and "sorting" work in a single .xsl file? As noted, I tried using node-set with the msxsl namespace, but because it is an extension method and apparently not known to the program I am using (XMLSpy)

Comment: It's too bad you have omitted the conversion part.

Comment: If you use XMLSpy, why are you restricted to XSLT 1? And the XSLT 1 processor in XMLSpy, as far as I know, doesn't require the use of a `node-set` extension function, it lets you use result tree fragments in XPath selection just fine.

Comment: @michael.hor257k added the part to my question

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I am working with XMLSpy right now, but I am ultimately trying to make a XMLOnTheClient solution work with as many browsers as possible. That is why I said I am limited to XSLT1.0 as I read that many browsers do not support XSLT > 1.0. I got it working for Firefox now by using "node-set", however other browsers (Edge, Chrome) seem to not fully support all XSLT1.0 commands

Comment: Cross-browser XSLT 1 is a nightmare but Chrome supports both the `document` function as well as `exsl:node-set. Current Edge releases should support `document` but not `exsl:node-set`, you would need to switch to the Microsoft specific `msxsl:node-set`, testing with `function-available` in XSLT and branch. If you have working Firefox code and need help with other browsers, then I suggest to ask additional, specific questions for each problem separatately, i.e. for Chrome post specific, minimal but complete sample of XMLs, XSLT, result you want and result and errors you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example (minimized to the problem presented in your question):

**XML**

```
<data>
    <event time="2019-02-03T06:00:00.000"></event>
    <event time="2019-02-01T06:00:00.000"></event>
</data>
```

**b.xml**

```
<data>
    <event time="2019-035T06:00:00.000"></event>
    <event time="2019-033T06:00:00.000"></event>
</data>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <!-- CONVERT B -->
    <xsl:variable name="b">
        <xsl:for-each select="document('b.xml')/data/event">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="time">
                    <!-- the missing conversion part goes here -->
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- OUTPUT -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="event | exsl:node-set($b)/event">
            <xsl:sort select="@time" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <event time="2019-02-01T06:00:00.000"/>
  <event time="2019-02-02T06:00:00.000"/>
  <event time="2019-02-03T06:00:00.000"/>
  <event time="2019-02-04T06:00:00.000"/>
</data>
```

Comment: Besides, convertion function, input data normalization is the best approach.

Comment: Thank you! While XMLSpy does not support the node-sets as pointed out, your post made me consider trying it directly with a XMLOnTheClient solution. While it works in Firefox, Chrome seems to have difficulties with accessing the elements of b.xml by the command document('b.xml')

Comment: @diamon The `document()` function is part of the XSLT 1.0 specification.If your processor does not support it, it is not compliant with the specification - and I don't know what to suggest as a workaround.